# Unable to install packages in R -- Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed

Tags: r, package, installation

I have been using R Studio for years without any issues but today I am not able to install any packages.

When I use the following code:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

I just get this message:

```
Error in install.packages : Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
```

I have tried different mirrors and updated my R Studio to the latest version without any joy. My internet connection hasn't changed and is operating normally.

Any help hugely appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you type`getOption("repos")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggests you are getting an http redirect from the server. Changing the repo ought to fix it. There are many different repos you can try. I find the following very reliable:

```r
install.packages("dplyr", repos = c(CRAN = "https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/"))
```

---

EDIT

After some extensive trial-and-error, it looks as though it was the download method used by `install.packages` that was to blame, so the solution was:

```
install.packages("dplyr", method = "libcurl")
```

Comment: Probably not ideal for folks outsize of Oz though.  `https://cloud.r-project.org` is a CDN and hence "network-close" to everybody.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel good point. That's a UK repo actually, and I was making a lazy guess from the OP's user name. Of course, a couple of drat repos would make a handy backup - I see you're a fan. I suspect the OP's problem will resolve automatically anyway, but who knows?

Comment: Gee, fell for it again. Bristol, which I visited numerous times, ain't Brisbane, where I've been too.  Clearly ADHD at my end -- too many little balls in the air.  So yes, read "Oz" as "UK" :)

Comment: Hi both -- thanks very much for your thoughts but still giving me the same error. I have tried the Bristol option as well as Imperial (London) and the Dublin one (I'm based in Ireland)... but just keep getting the same error...

Comment: @ThomasDeane is it a work pc? Has a firewall been installed?

Comment: @Allan Cameron Personal computer and no firewall or proxy in operation...

Comment: @ThomasDeane are you able to see the whole html document you are being sent? If you try `download.file("https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz", "~/dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz")` are you able to install it from source? If not, can you download it through a web browser and install it from source? Just as diagnostic tests of course

Comment: @AllanCameron seems to have downloaded ok:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1346k  100 1346k    0     0  2288k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2289k                               but not sure how i install from source -- am using a Mac

Comment: @ThomasDeane can you install it from source? Tools -> Install Packages -> Install From -> Package Archive File

Comment: @AllanCameron I then get the following: ERROR: dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘assertthat’, ‘glue’, ‘magrittr’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘R6’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘BH’, ‘plogr’ are not available for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/dplyr’

Comment: @ThomasDeane OK, so it sounds as though you can access the url, store the file and that R can read / attempt to install the package, which means there seems to be something wrong with the way the file is being accessed by `install.packages`. Any difference if you try `install.packages("dplyr", method = "libcurl")` or other methods like "curl", "wget", "wininet" or "internal"?

Comment: @AllanCameron -- Amazing -- the "libcurl" method worked, and it has loaded. Thank you so much for your help here. This has cost me about five hours today but I would never have got there without your help!

Answer (score 1):

For me, using `type="source"` solved. i.e.

```r
install.packages("dplyr", type="source")
```

Failing that, try [downloading Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and double clicking on it to install it, close your R session and try again, it should succeed.