# How to install packages in R when using Mac OS BigSur

Tags: r, rstudio

Ever since I updated to Mac BigSur, I have not been able to work with R, I am trying to install rstan/rstanarm, but I will never get there if I cannot install anything, do you have any suggestions in fixing the issue below, or alternatively suggesting a different way to install packages. Thanks!

Christian

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) -- "Shake and Throw"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[R.app GUI 1.74 (7950) x86_64-apple-darwin17.0]

[History restored from /Users/christianbasile/.Rapp.history]

> install.packages("rstan")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Error in if (res > nrow(m)) { : argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
> install.packages("rstan")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.case.edu/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.case.edu/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.case.edu/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.case.edu/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
2: package ‘rstan’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
> install.packages("tidyverse", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0:
  Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
> usethis::edit_r_profile()
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘usethis’
> install.packages("tidyverse", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0:
  Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
> R.home()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
> local({
+   r = getOption("repos")           
+   r["CRAN"] = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
+   options(repos = r)
+ })
> install.packages("tidyverse", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0:
  Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
> install.packages("dplyr", method = "libcurl")
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
>
```

Do you have any suggestions? I have been installing different versions of R, but same outcome. I know it may be something with the Rstart files, but I am unsure how to fix it. I am relatively new working with R. I will appreciate the help!!

Christian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install packages in R -- Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548749/unable-to-install-packages-in-r-line-starting-doctype-html-publi-is-m)

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: r2evans ok i can, how to edit my post? thanks.

Comment: @ottokassi thanks It did not Otto, I tried the examples in the link just now. Many thanks.